# Remove fragment in viewPager from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I got a viewPager inside it I have several fragment.

```
    providerViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    userRequest.add(1);

        fragmentPagerAdapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(HomeActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return userRequest.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return MyFragment.newInstance(position, userRequest.get(position));
            }
        };
        providerViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
```

userRequest is a arrayList of int, for each item in this list I create a MyFragment.

MyFragment contain the display view for each page.

```
view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ViewPager viewPager = ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getViewPager();
                FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter = ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getAdapter();
                ArrayList<Integer> ints = ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getRequest();

                viewPager.removeView(view);
                ints.remove(getArguments().getInt("position"));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

This is a onClickListener who is inside my fragment, I would like to remove this current fragment when I'm click on it.

As you can see I get the viewPager, the adapter and the arrayList from my Activity, and I try some method to remove this fragment, this work but I got some bug, for exemple if I remove an element at the middle of the view Pager I can't reach the element at the end. I would like to know if they are something much simple for remove fragment.

Comment: why are you removing the view from the view Pager ?

Comment: try to set the position of the view pager before deleting the fragment

Comment: The ViewPager is in charge of its own content. If you want to change something change the data in the adapter or the current position.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with this :

```
public void removeUserRequest(int position) {
    if (position > 0) {
        removeViewOnSwipe(position - 1);
    } else {
        removeViewOnSwipe(position);
    }
}

private void removeViewOnSwipe(int position) {
    userRequest.remove(position);
    if (userRequest.size() == 0) {
        providerViewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fragmentPagerAdapter = null;
    } else {
        fragmentPagerAdapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(HomeActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return userRequest.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return ProviderSwipeListFragment.newInstance(position, userRequest.get(position));
            }
        };
        providerViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
        providerViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
}
```

removeUserRequest is the method call in the Fragment.
removeViewOnSwipe : we remove the item in the userRequest list. And after that I create a new Adapter. And finally set the correct new position with

```
providerViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

I try do to it without recreat a new adapter with using notifyDataSetChanged instead, but I got some bug, the previous fragment can be visible if the user scroll a lot on the end of the swipe list